# dynamically populated menus visibility to search engines

Tags: jquery, menu, search-engine

I want to populate a jQuery menu from ajax calls which retrieves menus from the db.  Since the `<li>` items will not show up in view source html, but are added to the DOM in the jQuery ready function, what do search engines see as the html?  Do they see the empty menu structure (i.e., the browser source) or do they see the populated li items?  My guess (and hope) is it's the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search engines will typically *not* execute JavaScript code when crawling a page. For this reason I don't believe your menus will show up in the DOM.

Another option might be to actually render out the menu as an unordered list when the page loads, but style the list with a `display:none` so your visitors don't see it, but a search engine will.

Try viewing your site with one of these tools, which will (effectively) simulate a search engine crawl.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587

http://www.delorie.com/web/lynxview.html

http://www.webconfs.com/search-engine-spider-simulator.php

**[EDIT]**

Actually, Google does provide a workaround for their bot to crawl AJAX content *if* you follow these standards: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

It would appear Bing and Yahoo also adopted these standards: http://searchengineland.com/bing-now-supports-googles-crawlable-ajax-standard-84149